# Wrong last employment date entered in resignation letter

Tags: resignation, notice-period

I handed in my notice to employer. I have a three month notice period.

On my letter I have written that I have handed in my notice in accordance with contract, 3 months, with my last employment date being August 22nd 2018.

However upon going over my dates in my head again I’ve realised my 3 month end date is actually in September.  I counted June when I should have stated counting from the next month as I’ve worked most of June.

I specifically stated 3 months notice - but miscalculated my end date.

I need to submit the termination request into the HR system as a next step with my superior.

Will this be an issue? Do I just modify the date on the HR system? Do I send a letter immediately noting the actual end date?

Answer (score 1):

It was a simple mistake, with no means to break the contract on your end. You need to let them know you are not intentionally trying to break that contract.

State that your last employment date in the notification was intended to be 3 months in accordance to your contract, but was incorrect due to a miscalculation. If they are fine with the date you submitted, you will go with that, but if not you would like to change it to 3 months from the day you made the notice in order to respect your contract.

Ultimately in the end, ask them how they would like you to proceed.

Comment: Do you think I could say something like this ......          As stated in my contract and within my resignation letter dated June 18th I have provided my 3 month notice period to the company. 

My last employment date in the notification was intended to be 3 months in accordance to my contract, but was incorrect due to a miscalculation. I will amend the date on the HR system to 18/9/18.

Comment: @Fx128 Yes, if you were the one who registered it in the HR system in the first place that sounds good. If an HR rep added it after receiving your notification, I would change the last line to something like, "Should I amend the date on the HR system to 18/9/18?"  -- It depends on what the rules are for editing existing items in your company.

Comment: I’ve just submitted a letter. My superior is supposed to add it in the system.

Comment: @Fx128 Then I would suggesting asking if they want you to update it unless you know for sure they won't be upset with you updating it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your manager is a decent person, everything will be fine. It’s something you should check very soon.

Worst case, if your manager hates you, the company may reject your notice ( they don’t have to accept a two month notice if your contract says three) or they can accept your two months notice and you are gone one month earlier than planned.